# SUM() function not displaying sum...not returning ANY records

Tags: php, sql

Okay...so, I've got everything written correctly...however, when trying to get the grand total of the SQL row "Total", it no longer gives me an error...it just returns blank.

**CODE**:
    `$query2 = "SELECT SUM(Total) AS Total_Owed FROM public debts";`
    `$sum = mysql_query($query2);`
    `echo "<tr><td align=\"left\" colspan=\"2\">$" . $row['Total_Owed'] . "</td><td>&nbsp;   </td></tr>";`

When it's runs, it simply displays: `$` and nothing more.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks guys for everything...I got it working using the mysql_fetch_row method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing mysql_query, you also need to fetch the row, so change your code to include this

```
$row = mysql_fetch_row($sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to retrieve the query result first:

```
<?php
$query2 = "SELECT SUM(Total) AS Total_Owed FROM public debts";
$objResults = mysql_query($query2);
$arrRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($objResults)
echo "<tr><td align=\"left\" colspan=\"2\">$" . $arrRow['Total_Owed'] . "</td><td>&nbsp; </td></tr>";
```